# Perl code for splitting a file, if 16s and 23s is present. and copy into a single file

Tags: perl, split

I have a file from which I want to search for the string "16S" and "23S" and extract the section containing these strings into two separate files.

Input file:

```
start
description Human 16S rRNA
**some text**
**some text**
//
start
description Mouse 18S rRNA
some text
some text
//
start
description Mouse 23S rRNA
some text
some text
//
```

Expected output:
File1 for 16S:

```
start
description Human 16S rRNA
some text
some text
//
```

File2 for 23S:

```
start
description Mouse 23S rRNA
some text
some text
//
```

My code used:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl   
# default output file is /dev/null - i.e. dump any input before
# the first [ entryN ] line.

$outfile='FullrRNA.gb';
open(OUTFILE,">",$outfile) || die "couldn't open $outfile: $!";

while(<>) {
  # uncomment next two lines to optionally remove comments (startin with
  # '#') and skip blank lines.  Also removes leading and trailing
  # whitespace from each line.
  # s/#.*|^\s*|\s*$//g;
  # next if (/^$/)

  # if line begins with 'start', extract the filename
  if (m/^\start/) {
    (undef,$outfile,undef) = split ;
    close(OUTFILE);
    open(OUTFILE,">","$outfile.txt") || die "couldn't open $outfile.txt: $!";
  } else {
    print OUTFILE;
  }
}
close(OUTFILE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can rely on `<LF>//<LF>` as a record separator, then with GNU `awk`, that could be just:

```
gawk -v 'RS=\n//\n' '
  {ORS=RT}; / 16S /{print > "file1"}; / 23S /{print > "file2"}' < file
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd solve this with `awk` rather than by Perl, sorry.

```
/^\/\// && file { file = file ".out";
                  print section ORS $0 >file;
                  file = "" }

/^description/ && match($0, p) && file = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) {}

/^start/        { section = $0; next       }
                { section = section ORS $0 }
```

Running it on your data (you use `p='expression'` to pick out the sections that you want):

```
$ awk -f script.awk p='16S|23S' file.in
$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel   64 Aug 28 12:10 16S.out
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel   56 Aug 28 12:10 23S.out
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  176 Aug 28 11:51 file.in
-rw-r--r--  1 kk  wheel  276 Aug 28 12:09 script.awk
$ cat 16S.out
start
description Human 16S rRNA
**some text**
**some text**
//
$ cat 23S.out
start
description Mouse 23S rRNA
some text
some text
//
```

The first block in the script executes if we find a end-of-section marker (a line starting with `//`) and if the output filename (`file`) is non-empty.  It appends `.out` to the current filename and outputs the saved section followed by the current input line to the file. It then empties the `file` variable.

The second block is empty, but the pattern will match lines starting with `description` and will go on to match the line against the regular expression given on the command line (`p`).  If it matches, the part that matches will be picked out and used as the filename.

The third block executes if we find a line starting with the word `start` and it just sets the saved section text to the current line, discarding any old text that was saved therein. It then skips to the beginning of the script and considers the next input line.

The last block is executed for all other lines in the file and it appends the current line to the currently saved section.